# Finding the height of a ball modeled with $f(x) = -2(x-1)^2+7\,$?

Tags: functions, physics, quadratics

Finding the height of a ball modeled with $f(x) = -2(x-1)^2+7$.

The position of a ball after it is thrown is modeled with the function  $$f(x) = −2(x−1)^2 +7$$ in vertex form, where $y$ is the height (feet above ground) and $x$ is the horizontal distance (feet) of the ball from where it is thrown.

What is the height of the ball when it is thrown?  Which form of the function did you use?

Explain why you used this form of the function to answer the question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731014

Comment: Plugin $x=0$ in $f(x)$ and see what you get

Comment: As stated the problem ("What is the height of the ball when it is thrown?") doesn't make much sense.  Time is not one of your variables. $y$ is the height in feet above ground "of a ball after it is thrown", but any position of the ball might correspond to when the ball is thrown.  Indeed the variable $y$ doesn't appear in your equation for $f(x)$, so it's an unstated assumption that $y = f(x)$ as both are described as "the height of a ball".

Answer (score 1):

$$ y=-2 (x-1)^2 +7$$
Plug in $x=0$ , $y= 5$.

The  parabolic trajectory corresponds to a ball thrown ( a projectile) before attaining its maximum height $y=7$ at $x=1$.